# System.Net.Quic is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, openssl, quic

I am trying to make app using Quic protocol on C#. My windows version is incompatable so I used my vm with ubuntu 22.04. I installed libmsquic from microsoft package repository and yet I get this exception each time. There are static "IsSupported" properties for QuicConnection and QuicListener ,each of them returns false.

One detail I noticed is that libmsquic is installed on `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` instead of '/usr/lib' but I don't think It's a big deal. I also checked for TLS 1.3 using `openssl ciphers -v | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq` command, 1.3 is listed. Installed dotnet version is 8.0.100.